# How to pass array to bash shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell, shell-script

How do I pass an array as a variable from a first bash shell script to a second script.

first.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
AR=('foo' 'bar' 'baz' 'bat')
sh second.sh "$AR" # foo
sh second.sh "${AR[@]}" # foo
```

second.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
ARR=$1
echo ${ARR[@]}
```

In both cases, the result is `foo`. But the result I want is `foo bar baz bat`.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The `AR` array is passed via the first argument to `second.sh`.

first.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
AR=('foo' 'bar' 'a space' 'bat')
printf "AR array contains %d elements: " ${#AR[@]}
printf "%s " "${AR[@]}"
printf "\n"
./second.sh "$AR"
./second.sh "$(printf "(" ; printf "'%s' " "${AR[@]}" ; printf ")")"
```

Note that `sh` is not used anymore to run the `second.sh` script.

These chained `printf` are used to forge a single parameter that will be safe if some array elements contain space chars.

second.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a ARR=$1
printf "ARR array contains %d elements: " ${#ARR[@]}
printf "%s " "${ARR[@]}"
printf "\n"
```

### ----

For a solution where the `AR` array is passed using any number of arguments to the `second.sh` script.

first.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
AR=('foo' 'bar' 'a space' 'bat')
printf "AR array contains %d elements: " ${#AR[@]}
printf "%s " "${AR[@]}"
printf "\n"
./second.sh "$AR"
./second.sh "${AR[@]}"
```

second.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
ARR=( "$@" )
printf "ARR array contains %d elements: " ${#ARR[@]}
printf "%s " "${ARR[@]}"
printf "\n"
```

### ----

The test:

```
$ chmod +x *sh
$ ./first.sh
AR array contains 4 elements: foo bar a space bat
ARR array contains 1 elements: foo
ARR array contains 4 elements: foo bar a space bat
```